# Retrofit cannot extract JSON in an object

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am studying how to use Retrofit to stop using `AsyncTask`. I have an interface named `Network` that makes my GET request, a `ServiceGenerator` class that creates my `Retrofit.Builder` and my HTTP interceptor and finally my `MainActivity` (I also have implemented the object class named `Results`).

The problem is, in my `onResponse` method (`.enqueue`) in `MainActivity`: I don't know how to extract JSON and put a "name" tag in the view.

Here is my `ServiceGenerator` class:

```java
public class ServiceGenerator {
    //URL base do endpoint. Deve sempre terminar com /
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://randomuser.me/";

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        //Instancia do interceptador das requisições

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        //httpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build();

        //Instância do retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Here is my interface `Network`:

```java
public interface Network {

    @GET("api/")
    Call<Results> randomUser();

}
```

Finally, the main activity:

```java
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView nome;
    private TextView sobrenome;
    private TextView email;
    private TextView endereco;
    private TextView cidade;
    private TextView estado;
    private TextView username;
    private TextView senha;
    private TextView nascimento;
    private TextView telefone;
    private ImageView foto;
    private ProgressDialog load;
    public String gender;
    public Results results;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://randomuser.me/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        sobrenome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sobrenome);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        endereco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        cidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cidade);
        estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estado);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        senha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.senha);
        nascimento = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nascimento);
        telefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);

        Network network = ServiceGenerator.createService(Network.class);

         Call<Results> requestUser = network.randomUser();

        requestUser.enqueue(new Callback<Results>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Results> call, Response<Results> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
                    progress.setTitle("sending...");
                    progress.show();
                    Results r = response.body();

                    /*MAYBE I SHOULD PUT SOMETHING HERE:*/

                    if (r != null) {

                        System.out.println();

                       // r.setGender(results.getGender());

                        nome.setText((CharSequence) results.setName(r.getName()));

                        //System.out.println("USER 2: " + response.raw() );

                        //r.setGender(r.getGender());
                        //Results r = new Results();

                        progress.dismiss();

                      //  nome.setText(results.gender.toString());

                        // System.out.println("random user: CARAIO  " + user.random);
                           //nome.setText((CharSequence) r.gender);

                    } else Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"ERROR IN GET JSON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Results> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

My `Results` class also:

```java
public class Results {

    public static String gender;

    public Results(){};

    public static String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public static void setGender(String gender) {
        Results.gender = gender;
    }

    public List<Name> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Object setName(List<Name> name) {
        this.name = name;
        return null;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(List<Location> location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Login> getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(List<Login> login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public List<Picture> getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(List<Picture> picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public List<Name> name;
    public List<Location> location;
    public String email;
    public List<Login> login;
    public String phone;
    public List<Picture> picture;

}
```

If you guys could help, it will be very gratefull, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/jackson
add it to gradle and sync.
While creating retrofit instance, call on builder

`.setConverter(new JacksonConverter())`

Use jackson for json deserialization.
Update your model class using

`@JsonProperty("put name of field here")`

Then all should work correctly/

Comment: You are trying to resolve with Jackson, i never used before, do you think is it better than GSon? (with better i mean "less complicated" huehue).

Comment: Its pretty easy to use and most cases its faster than gson. It has a lot of features and optional stuff, but it's enough to know the basics for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Network Interface like this

```
public interface Network {

    @GET("api/")
    Call<RandomUserServiceResponse> randomUser();

}
```

add this response Model in your project. It is the base response for your JSON response

```
 public class RandomUserServiceResponse {

    private List<Result> results = null;
   // private Info info;

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}
```

after you do all of this your response

```
 Call<RandomUserServiceResponse> requestUser = network.randomUser();

        requestUser.enqueue(new Callback<RandomUserServiceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RandomUserServiceResponse> call, Response<RandomUserServiceResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
                    progress.setTitle("sending...");
                    progress.show();
                    RandomUserServiceResponse r = response.body();



                /* if you want to get NAME tag please */
                Name name = r.getResults().getName();
               /* now you can get Name properties 
               name.getTitle(),name.getFirst(),name.getLast() */




                    if (r != null) {

                        System.out.println();

                       // r.setGender(results.getGender());

                        nome.setText((CharSequence) results.setName(r.getName()));

                        //System.out.println("USER 2: " + response.raw() );


                        //r.setGender(r.getGender());
                        //Results r = new Results();



                        progress.dismiss();

                      //  nome.setText(results.gender.toString());


                        // System.out.println("random user: CARAIO  " + user.random);
                           //nome.setText((CharSequence) r.gender);


                    } else Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"ERROR IN GET JSON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RandomUserServiceResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

here is your result class

```
public class Result {

    private String gender;
    private Name name;
    private Location location;
    private String email;
    private Login login;
    private String dob;
    private String registered;
    private String phone;
    private String cell;
    private Id id;
    private Picture picture;
    private String nat;

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Login getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(Login login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public void setRegistered(String registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    public void setCell(String cell) {
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Picture getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(Picture picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getNat() {
        return nat;
    }

    public void setNat(String nat) {
        this.nat = nat;
    }

}
```

and this is the Name Class

```
public class Name {

    private String title;
    private String first;
    private String last;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

}
```

and your Picture Class

```
public class Picture {

    private String large;
    private String medium;
    private String thumbnail;

    public String getLarge() {
        return large;
    }

    public void setLarge(String large) {
        this.large = large;
    }

    public String getMedium() {
        return medium;
    }

    public void setMedium(String medium) {
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

}
```

this is your Login class

```
public class Login {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String salt;
    private String md5;
    private String sha1;
    private String sha256;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    public String getMd5() {
        return md5;
    }

    public void setMd5(String md5) {
        this.md5 = md5;
    }

    public String getSha1() {
        return sha1;
    }

    public void setSha1(String sha1) {
        this.sha1 = sha1;
    }

    public String getSha256() {
        return sha256;
    }

    public void setSha256(String sha256) {
        this.sha256 = sha256;
    }

}
```

here is Location class

```
public class Location {

    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Integer postcode;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Integer getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(Integer postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

}
```

this is your Info class (you don't need to import this one )

```
public class Info {

    private String seed;
    private Integer results;
    private Integer page;
    private String version;

    public String getSeed() {
        return seed;
    }

    public void setSeed(String seed) {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public Integer getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Integer results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

and the last one is ID class

```
public class Id {

    private String name;
    private Object value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried what you said @Umut but now it appears the message on my MainActivity onFailure method(enqueue) "+ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 38 path $.results[0].name
"... it appears that i am instanciating an object instead of an array in my object class, should i change my Results class into an array?? i never seen that in retrofit tutorials

Comment: @4ury0n i update the answer with all models please take the new model from answer